# How can insert data to MySQL in Swift 3 via Alamofire?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift3, alamofire

I want to save data in MySQL. I am using php and my codes:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//Connect to Database
include "Connect.php";

//getting values
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//query
$q="INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ($name,$email)";
if (mysqli_query($connection, $q)) {
    $response['error']=false;
    $response['message']="New record created successfully";
} else {
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']="Error: " . $q . "<br>" .     mysqli_error($connection);
}

echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

And I am using Alamofire and my codes:

```
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "name": "xxxx",
        "email": "yyyy"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(api, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in

        if let data = response.data {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("Response: \(json)")
        }
    }
```

When I run the Xcode, I am getting this error:

```
Response: Optional("{\"error\":true,\"message\":\"Error: INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (xxxx,yyyy)<br>\"}")
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: for starters, it is wide open to **SQL Injection** attacks. use **parameterized statements** to protect yourself, while solving your problem automatically because with parameterized statements, you don't need to *wrap string values in quotes* anymore.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering **SQL Injection** attacks, I think the problem in SQL is the single quotes are missed for values. Improvement:

```
$q="INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (\'$name\',\'$email\')";
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this and check for column name and type

```
INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES('abcd', 'abcd@mail.com')
```

Comment: Its just an example so I mentioned AccountDetails